# Dark Mode 4 Chats

Tags: script, chat, dark-mode

A userscript that adds Dark Mode to Stack Exchange Chats, while also allowing you to customize themes and colors!

**Version 0.2: still beta**

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: DarkMode4Chats]

### About

Since the introduction of Dark Mode, we have not seen it being expanded to chats. This userscript adds a customizable Dark Theme to your chat experience!

#### License

DarkMode4Chats is licensed under the [MIT License](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/LICENSE)

#### Download

Minified and non-minified versions can be found here:

https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/tree/main/scripts/dark-mode-4-chats/src/v0.2

#### Platform

#### Browser Support

| IE | Chrome | Firefox | Safari | Edge | Opera |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ❌ | ✔️ 20+ | ✔️ 29+ | ✔️ 12.1 + | ✔️ 14+ | ✔️ 11.5 - 12.1, 17+ |

### Contact

#### Contributors

[Spectric](https://stackapps.com/users/76056/spectric?tab=profile)

The following helped provide feedback and test out the product:

- [Scratte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte)
- [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter)

### Code

Uses jQuery and HTML5 Web Storage API to preserve your theme preferences.

### Examples

#### Theme

[image]

[image]

#### Customization Menu

[image: DarkMode4Chats - Customizing]

Menu can be shown/hidden by clicking the settings icon on the top left corner.

Comment: Thank you for this. There is only one issue as it doesn't handle the one-box links "correctly" https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpirQ.png And I actually cannot get to edit the colors. When clicking on `Dark Mode for Chats` on top of the page, nothing happens.